# Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mysql, concrete5, concrete

I'm currently moving my concrete5.7 setup from localhost to a live server. First thing I did was export the SQL database and import it on the server, however this is giving me an error:

```
Error
SQL query:

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `config`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `config` (

 `configNamespace` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `configGroup` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
 `configItem` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
 `configValue` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (  `configNamespace` ,  `configGroup` ,  `configItem` ) ,
KEY  `configGroup` (  `configGroup` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

MySQL said: 

#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

I'm aware that the key is too long but is there any freedom to change? I've tried changing the database collation to latin1 but it did not work.

What settings can I change?

Thank you for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

That is a poor choice of primary key - you do not need 1000 bytes of entropy to make a row unique
If there is no natural choice of primary key, you can generate a surrogate key for the row.

e.g. replace

```
 PRIMARY KEY (  `configNamespace` ,  `configGroup` ,  `configItem` ) ,
```

with

```
 configId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

This should not be a breaking change for an application which uses the above.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `config` (
    configId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    configNamespace VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
    configGroup VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
    configItem VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
    configValue LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    UNIQUE (configNamespace, configGroup,  configItem) ,   
    KEY  `configGroup` (  `configGroup` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

This creates the auto-incremented primary key for the table.  In addition, it keeps the unique constraint on the three columns previously used for the primary key.